# Multi Advertisement of different Bluetooth protocols (pybluez)

Tags: linux, python-3.x, bluetooth-lowenergy, hid, pybluez

I'm trying to write PyBluez scripts that serve both as a HID keyboard and GATT server.

I have both scripts working separately, but I am not sure how to merge them together, both advertisements need to run in parallel without affecting each other.

The BLE protocol has a bunch of different characteristics (read/write/notify) assigned to it whereas the HID server would listen for keyboard input.

The HID protocol is based on the following git code:
https://github.com/SySS-Research/bluetooth-keyboard-emulator/tree/master/server